Is there a grammatical name to this tense case?
I came across a sentence below in a website for English study in Japan.

There are a lot of presentations today. The judges will give thought to how each of the presenters performed their talks, and evaluate them.

In this sentence structure, the speaker cannot help using
the past tense verb performed, even though a presentation
have not started yet , right?
So my question is as the title.
Is there a grammatical name to the case like that?
I mean the case that the past tense verb is used when the speaker refers to the future action, but past action from 'the judge's' view..So the speaker uses the past tense verb like performed
   now    past actions from the judge's view


--the speaker--->---
--presenter's talks--------->------judges will give thought to their talks and  evaluate ------>>>future

The sentence is simply describing what the judges will do after each talk, or after all of the talks have been given.

The whole premise for this question is incorrect, because the past tense is not required in your example. This is a perfectly valid sentence structure:

The judges will give thought to how each of the presenters perform/s their talks, and evaluate them.

I've qualified the precise form of the verb. The tension between each of (singular) and their talks (plural) makes the choice of singular or plural verb somewhat tricky. But there is no doubt about the tense, which can be a simple present tense.
Note that I'm not saying the past tense is wrong. The writer can choose the past tense if he wants to emphasise the performance took place before the judges' thinking and evaluation. But the point is that past tense is not required, it's simply a choice you make to communicate your intended meaning. As such, it's no different from other tense choices.

There's nothing wrong with the question and no need to reframe it. The OP asked what a particular construction is called, not if there are other ways of writing the same thing.

I agree that it's OK to ask any question if the OP doesn't know. It's also OK for me to answer the question honestly, which is what I did. I don't believe there is any official construction; that's my answer. We're simply talking about a choice of tenses. If I'm right, that's the most helpful thing to say. (Note also that the OP asks if they have to use the past tense, so I'm not reframing anyway. Just answering.)

Yes, it's called the future perfective perspective.
I like this explanation on Wikipedia:

The future perfect is a verb form or construction used to describe an event that is expected or planned to happen before a time of reference in the future, such as will have finished in the English sentence "I will have finished by tomorrow."

In your example, it is used to state what will happen after something else has finished.

There's no perfect in the OP's sentence. It is a simple past.

What @TimR said. The future perfective would be how each of the presenters has performed their talk, which is even more clunky than the actual past in the future as written. I'm with Peter on this one. KISS. Simple (singular) Present ...how each of the presenters performs their talk is all it needs.
